# sherlock action bar not working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am making a action bar using sherlock action bar but it is not shown when i run it.This is the code:

```
public class NaseebactionbarActivity extends SherlockActivity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
        ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

        actionbar.addTab(PlayerTab);
        actionbar.addTab(StationsTab);

        actionbar.show();
    }
```

please tell me what is the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: What version are you running as 4 is vastly different from 3. I have produced YouTube videos to help set it up http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY

Answer (score 2):

Extend your `Activity` from `SherlockFragmentActivity` instead of `SherlockActivity`:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest, be sure to set the theme of your application to :
`android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`